# Using PHP in html to call a file through

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Okay so I have a file upload button for images, now when the user uploads their image it also displays it in a 550px by 550px box so they can view their upload. What I need is that when they then go to the next page their image is also displayed on that page in a smaller box / as a thumbnail. Ive managed to find this PHP code that says it can recall the last uploaded image but I was just wondering how you would link that to the file upload button and how you can display it on the next page in a smaller box..... ? Any suggestions or solutions are appreciated!(Been trying to figure this out for a week now and decided to seek others help)

```
$path = "/path/to/my/dir"; 

$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';    

$d = dir($path);
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
  // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
  if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
    $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
    $latest_filename = $entry;
  }
}

// now $latest_filename contains the filename of the file that changed last
```

Comment: Displaying the last file by file time seems like it'll fail the moment there is more than one user on the site at the same time.  Why not just put some identifier to the image in session state and use that to display it on the next page?

Comment: why not simply store last uploaded image url  in a session variable?

Comment: Okay and how would I do that.... to provide more information: This is for a shop..... they obviously upload the image see the image then click add to cart which takes them to the cart and I need it so that that image is then displayed alongside the product..... then when they upload another image to a separate product it does the same but without removing/replacing the other image?

Comment: so where is cart data stored? Just combine image array with cart data

Comment: @G.Gibson: Where exactly are you stuck?  What have you done so far and what isn't working?  So far what you're describing is too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @David I have the file upload button etc. I just need a hand transferring the image uploaded from one page to another and keeping it there through the checkout prcess so it then attaches itself to an email to me when the order is placed....

Comment: @charlietfl Im using shopify so I'm just finding out now where that information is stored and if I can access it....

Comment: @G.Gibson: Once you have the image stored server-side, presumably you have some way of identifying it?  A database ID, a file name, something like that.  Just store that identifier in session state and use it on later pages to display the image.

Comment: at the moment the file transfers to the cart as a link but not an image file and is given a random name.....

Comment: @charlietfl shopify stores it on their own servers and I'm unsure if I can even access that, just finding out

Answer (score 0):

I would first use `move_uploaded_file ( $tmp , $unique_filename )` to move/rename the uploaded file to a unique name.

I would then use php superglobals to carry the unique file name over to the next page. For instance using `$_SESSION['UPLOADED_FILE'] = $unique_filename` on the upload page, and simply recalling `$_SESSION['UPLOADED_FILE']` on the next.